# $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$, then $ST$ is invertible if and only if $S$ and $T$ are both invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ is *finite-dimensional* and that $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$, then $ST$ is *invertible* if and only if $S$ and $T$ are both *invertible*.

**Proof.** $(\Rightarrow).$ Assume that $ST$ is *invertible* and $T(v_1)=T(v_2)$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are arbitrary vectors in $V$ it then follows that $ST(v_1)=ST(v_2)$ but as $ST$ is *invertible* and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *invertible* therefore $v_1=v_2$ which implies that $T$ is *invertible* and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *invertible*.

Now let $w$ be an arbitrary vector in V, since $ST$ is *invertible* and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *surjective* it follows that for some $u\in V$, $STu = S(Tu)= w$, evidently $Tu\in V$ thus $S$ is *surjective* and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *invertible*.

$(\Leftarrow). $ Assume now that $S$ and $T$ are *invertible* and  $STu_1=STu_2$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are arbitrary vectors in $V$ since $S,T$ are *invertible* and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *surjective* it follows that for some $w_1,w_2\in V$, $w_1=Tu_1$ and $w_2=Tu_2$ consequently $Sw_1=Sw_2$ but $STu_1=STu_2$ and the *injectivity* of $S$ imply that $w_1=Tu_1=Tu_1=w_2$ and by similar reasoning we can conclude that $u_1=u_2$.

It then follows that $\mathbf{3.69}$ that $ST$ is injective and by $\mathbf{3.69}$ *invertible*.

$\blacksquare$

> NOTE: Here $\mathbf{3.69}$ is the result that given a
>   *finite-dimensional* vector space $V$ for any $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ the following are equivalent
>
> -Invertibility
>
> -Surjectivity
>
> -Injectivity

Comment: This is fine, but I suggest using more periods and commas.